# JSON.Net Convert Date on Output to XML

Tags: datetime, json.net

I try to convert JSON to XML with Dateformat like this:

Orginal:

```
{
    "contract": {
        "startDate": "2015-08-15T02:00:00+02:00",...}
}
```

Result should be in XML:

```
<startdate>15.08.2018<\startdate>
```

I tried these aproaches:

1)

```
string tmp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy" });`
```

this does the conversion in most cases well

2)

created method and decorated the JSON-elements

```
public class DateFormatConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateFormatConverter(string format)
    {
        DateTimeFormat = format;
    }
}
```

called like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "dd.MM.yyy")]
    [JsonProperty("startDate", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

and did no further conversion, but runs on error (no valid DateTime-Format) ->maybe the result of NULL-values?

How can I convert the Output correctly?

Comment: 1) How are you converting it currently?  2) Do you want to convert to UTC or keep in local time?  If you keep in local time, information will get lost.

Comment: If you can share the code from one of your attempts to solve the problem, that would increase your chances of getting an answer.  See [ask] which suggests ***Help others reproduce the problem** ... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: thanks for your answer. I edited the question to hopefully be more clear. I don't want to convert to UTC

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand your question.  Your title asks *JSON.Net Convert Date on Output to XML* but your code shows that you are writing JSON not XML.  And your `JsonConverter` will have no effect at all when outputting to XML.  Can you [edit] your question to share a full [mcve] showing what you are doing now?  As it is you are only including code fragments.  Also, can you explain what you mean by *this does the conversion in most cases well*?  Is there a problem here that you need solved, or is the problem with approach 2) which never works?

Comment: The first thing to do is to Deserialize JSON to XML using:

`XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);`